# A conditionned SQL query [VueJS]

Tags: php, sql, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning VueJS and I cannot wrap my head around the select part (In my case, I used the Single select from the tutorial page.

Until now, I let the "user" fill the unique search box AND my query (located in data.php) was this one:

```
    case 'list':
    $b      = new book;
    $req    = "SELECT id, isbn, ddc, title FROM book WHERE 1=1 ";
    if(strlen($search)>0) {
        $req .= "AND isbn LIKE '%$search%' OR ddc LIKE '%$search%' ";
    }

    $req.= "ORDER BY title LIMIT 0,50";

    $fields = array("id","isbn","ddc", "title");
    $res    = $c->StructList($req,$fields,"json");
    echo $res;
    break;
```

Which renders in the index.php, this view:

[Old rendition until now with only one search box - WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EJIm.png)

Now, I try to get a step before the search box.

[New version with a SELECT OPTION - NOT WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbB7g.png)

I guess it can looks stupid to not letting one search box and whatever (ISBN or Dewey Decimal Classification) can be filled but it's a personal training I put myself through for this training.

Both of this classification in my examples come from 2 different others tables of my database (ISBN_code AND DDC_code).

In my index.php file, I followed the select option from the Vue.js tutorial.

```
<select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
    <option>Through the ISBN</option>
    <option>Through the Dewey Decimal Classification</option>
</select>

<span>Selected : {{ selected }}</span><br><br>
```

and on my data.php, now I wrote:

```
        $b      = new book;
    $req    = "SELECT id, isbn, ddc, title FROM book WHERE 1=1 ";
    if(strlen($search)>0) {
        $req .= "AND {{selected}} LIKE '%$search%' ";
    }

    $req.= "ORDER BY title LIMIT 0,50";

    $fields = array("id","isbn","ddc", "title");
    $res    = $c->StructList($req,$fields,"json");
    echo $res;
```

=> I wrote a 1=1 in order to avoid to get the query working even if the condition of the search bar (one line below) is not fullfield.

And lastly in the app.js file, I wrote:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el:"#app",
data:{
    list:[],
    search:"",
    selected:''
},
mounted:function(){
    this.GetList();
},
methods:{

    GetListe:_.debounce(function(search = ""){
        var scope = this;
        $.ajax({
            url:"data.php?case=list",
            type:"POST",
            data:{search},
            success:function(res){
                scope.list = JSON.parse(res);
            },
            error:function(){
            }
        });
    },500),

},
```

});

I don't get how to get the query works with this method where the user has to select first a classification code.

Should I modify my query or v-bind something? like in the example of https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Check out this link about event handling in Vue: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Right now, your ajax request doesn't pass `selected` to your php code, only search, since the `data` option is only `{search}`. I don't know exactly what format the php needs to take in, but it is probably something along the lines of

`{search: [searchValue], selected: [selectedValue]}`

To actually trigger the ajax call, you need to hook up your GetList method to an element controlled by Vue. Based on the code you shared, it looks like you're only using Vue to control the dropdown, so you could trigger a request like this:

```
<select v-model="selected" v-on:change="GetList()">
```

As it stands now, that will fire the GetList, but doesn't make use of your dropdown. If you modify GetList to take the value of the dropdown, it will include it as well:

```
GetList: _.debounce(function(search = ""){
    var scope = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:"data.php?case=list",
        type:"POST",
        data:{search: scope.search, selected: scope.selected},
        success:function(res){
            scope.list = JSON.parse(res);
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
},500),
```

Note that on the `data` line, it is referring to `this.search` and `this.selected`. That's how you can access the value stored in the `data` object. By having `v-model="selected"` on the dropdown in your template, it is bound to the `selected` property in the `data` object, so its value can be accessed within the method with `this.selected`.

Also note that the name of the method is `GetList`. The code you pasted is `GetListe`, but you try to call it on the `mounted()` lifecycle hook as `GetList()`, so I'm assuming the method declaration `GetListe` is a typo.

I would try hooking up your `GetList` method to the `change` event on the `select` element, perhaps add some console logs to better understand what's going on, and change the value in the dropdown a few times and see what happens. I would also get rid of the debounce, just to simplify as you are trying to understand it.

```
GetList: function(search = "") {
    console.log("GetList()");
    console.log("search: " + this.search);
    console.log("selected: " + this.selected);
    var scope = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:"data.php?case=list",
        type:"POST",
        data:{search: scope.search, selected: scope.selected},
        success:function(res){
            scope.list = JSON.parse(res);
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
},
```

That should get you going in the right direction.

The next step would be to bring your search bar into the vue template as well, bind your `search` data property as a `v-model` on the search bar, and trigger the `GetList` event when the `search` value is changed as well. Something like this:

```
<input v-model="search" v-on:change="GetList()">
```

Again, have console logs in the GetList method, play around with it a bit to understand what its doing.